# How to test POST call related API's without accessing Database

Tags: pytest, django-testing, django-tests, pytest-django, pytest-mock

I am trying to write a test case for a POST API call without accessing the database using pytest module in django. How can I approach this ? Can anyone help me on this? Thanks.

````
def test_security():
    request_data = {"security_data": [
        {
            ## Some data is here
        }]
    }

    response = client.post("/add-security/", request_data)
    print("response::::",response)```
````